# Eu posso retornar uma struct inicializando-a dentro de um return no ANSI C?

Tags: c, struct, return

Bom dia pessoal, eu gostaria de saber se eu consigo fazer algo deste tipo...

```c
typedef struct Result
{
   int low, high, sum;
} Result;

Result teste(){
   return {.low = 0, .high = 100, .sum = 150};
}
```

Eu sei que este não seria um jeito certo, porém há alguma forma de o fazer ou eu tenho que criar uma variável temporária na função para receber os valores e então retorna-la?

Answer (score 2):

Copia (com minha traducao) da [resposta do Ouah no Stack Overflow em ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25700804/can-i-return-a-initialized-struct-on-one-line-in-ansi-c).

Podes fazer isso usando um *compound literal* (literal composto):

```
Result test(void)
{
    return (Result) {.low = 0, .high = 100, .sum = 150};
}
```

`(){}` é o operador para literal composto que foi introduzido com a versao C99.

Answer (score 0):

O @pmg já disse tudo (+1); Só mais uma variante:

```
typedef struct Result { int low, high, sum; } Result;

Result teste(){
  return (Result){0,100,150};
}

int main(){
  printf("%d\n",teste().sum);
  return 0;
}
```

ou sem typedef:

```
struct Result { int low, high, sum; };

Result teste(){  
  return (struct Result){0,100,150};
}
```